# Conditional aggregation in SSAS

Tags: scope, ssas, mdx

I have a SCOPE statement in my cube that prevents aggregation of certain measures in incompatible dimension members are used:

```
SCOPE (MeasureGroupMeasures('Measure Group'), [User Type].[User Type].[All]);                                                                                        
this = IIF(DISTINCTCOUNT(NONEMPTY(EXISTING([User Type].[User Type].[All].Children)
                ,[Measures].[Measure Group Count])) > 1
       , NULL
       , [Measures].CurrentMember);
```

Basically if we are trying to aggregate data from the measure group for more than one "User Type", a null value is returned.
While this approach works fine, the performance leaves a lot to be desired.
Is there any way to achieve this that is much faster?

Thanks

Comment: Just tried changing DISTINCTCOUNT to COUNT definitely improves performance significantly (went from 44 seconds to 24 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

Add a Measure Group using the same Data Source as your User Type dimension. The only Measure should be a count e.g User Type Count, not visible. The only Dimension Relationship should be to the User Type dimension.

Now you can just say:

IIF ( [Measures].[User Type Count] > 1 , ...